# IllegalArgumentException Not an entity on a test

Tags: java, hibernate, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to test something, and for that I created a DummyEntity, which is in a package inside test folder. I added to the hibernate configuration sending

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(DummyEntity.class);
```

And the DummyEntity is like this (is in Scala):

```
@Entity(name = "dummy")
class DummyEntity{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Long =_
  @Column
  var name: String =_
  @Column
  var surname: String =_

}
```

The problem is that it's not finding DummyEntity as an entity, so I can't test it well.

I think that the test folder is not observable by hibernate when it builds the session factory, but I'm not sure.

Do I have to do something special in order to fix this? I don't know what else I can try.

Thank you!